# Extending the Leg of a Letter to Remove Sheimos

Tags: halacha, shemos-sacred-names, writing-printing, disposal

May one extend the letter Hey in God's name to turn it into a Kuf as a way of removing sheimos? My question is twofold:

1) Is there a problem of erasing God's name here, by taking a holy name of God and making it unholy?

2) Will this actually change the status of the document, or will it retain the status of sheimos?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is prohibited as erasing God's name. If you wrote יה as God's name and then want to follow it up with ודה to make the name יהודה, that is prohibited ([Soferim 5](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%9B%D7%AA_%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D_(%D7%93%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%A1_%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%98%D7%A8%D7%93%D7%9D_%D7%AA%22%D7%93)/%D7%94):2, [Keset Hasofer 12:3](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=8308&st=&pgnum=54)). Your case is even worse since you are acting on the letters of God's name themselves (cf. Lishkat Hasofer ibid.).

Comment: Consider clarifying if this works if you did it, despite the aveirah...